Laravel Mix does not give local url address
The other day I downloaded my laravel website from my server to make some updates. When I ran the test environment locally, the urls of my newly added Script files were not “localhost”. As a result, the script files cannot be found. Why is the file path of my scripts an internet address even though I run my project locally?
Developer tools / Network tab
webpack.mix.js;
mix.js('resources/js/homepage2.js', 'public/js').version();

in Blade file;
<script src="{{ mix('js/homepage2.js') }}"></script>

❌Not working because only redirecting to my website url.
<script src="{{ asset('js/homepage2.js') }}"></script>

✔️Working fine. Url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/homepage2.js. It's as it should be.
I haven't figured out how to do research for 3 days. Thanks in advance for your help.
I tried "npm run dev" or "npm run production" and it didn't make any difference.
I changed the APP_URL part inside the .env file and it didn't make any difference.

So this might happen if you're copying your files from your production to local and also include the "hot" files.
